# How to get friend request information in quickblox for android

Tags: quickblox

I want to know the current friend request status (if its accepted or still pending) in quickblox for android.Is there any way to store friend request information in quikblox or should i maintain my own remote database?

Answer (score 2):

in the onSuccess of Sing into chat use this code

```
QBRoster chatRosteR=QBChatService.getInstance().getRoster(QBRoster.SubscriptionMode.mutual, subscriptionListener);
```

and use this listener.

```
QBSubscriptionListener subscriptionListener = new QBSubscriptionListener() {
    @Override
    public void subscriptionRequested(final int userId) {
        Log.e("friend request", userId + "");
        //friend id
    }
};
```

Hope this will help you